# How to draw a circle and fills outside border with color

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was wondering if it's possible to achieve that in CSS 2/3 (or if not possible, in JS).

In fact my wish is instead of having this as an image, is to set the percent of filled color with a class (or in js if it's not possible)

[image]

Any tutorial/help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't achieve this result with css. You have to use a canvas element and a javascript framework like http://paperjs.org/

Comment: Okay, then do you have a tutorial for that in JS? I don't even know the english name of what i'm trying to do... it could help me fiding ressources on the web ;-)

Comment: At first try out some tutorials from http://paperjs.org/tutorials/ and after you finish them and understand this framework a little, you can build up an own script to animate a loading bar. or you do it relative static and use http://www.jqplot.com/tests/pie-donut-charts.php

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this with SVG. Define a gradient, then draw an arc, and fill it with the gradient. You can also specify inline markers on your path.

Comment: But the support for SVG by all browser is more than bad. Currently i work with SVG and it's driving me nuts.

Answer (score 0):

Set border-width to `1000px`. This trick worked for me.